# Time data does not match format '%c'

Tags: python, datetime, time, datetime-format

This is very unexpected behavior...

1. I create a time string using the `'%c'` directive.

   `%c` is the [Locale’s appropriate date and time representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime).
2. Then I try to parse the resulting time string, specifying the same `'%c'` as the string's format.
3. However this does not work as you can see from the error below. What am I missing?

I need to be able to store the time in a human-readable **localized** string, and then convert the string back into a `struct_time` so I can extract information from it.

(It is extremely important that the string be localized, and I of course don't want to write parsing algorithms for all locales around the world!)

```
# Ensure the locale is set.

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'

# 1. Create a localized time string using the '%c' directive.

import datetime
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%c')
time_stamp
'Mon 21 Dec 2020 03:47:55 PM '

# 2. Try to parse the string using the same directive used to create it.

import time
time.strptime(time_stamp, '%c')

# 3. Unexpected error...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 562, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Mon 21 Dec 2020 03:47:55 PM ' does not match format '%c'
```

Comment: cannot reproduce (on Windows, Python 3.9). `%c` works both ways for me, no matter if I use my default locale or set another one.

Answer (score 1):

Your locale is probably not configuring `.strftime("%c")` the way you expect and `.strptime` is objecting to the postfixed `%p` (`PM`)

Use [`locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.nl_langinfo) to build your format instead!

```py
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)
'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)
'%a %b %e %X %Y'
```

---

However, if you

- .. know the exact structure of the output, filter exact matches with a regex and then parse
- .. can control the format, don't bother to format it and directly use `time.time()`
- .. or always work in UTC and format as ISO 8601, deriving a tz-aware object and reading back with a custom parser (refer to [the **Caution** on `.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat))

  ```py
  >>> datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
  datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 22, 0, 4, 29, 537007, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
  ```
- use [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/), which is much "smarter" than the datetime builtin lib and properly supports a huge variety of locales

Comment: I understand the concept. You are telling the system to supply a format string appropriate for the locale. But how do I go from time_struct --> string --> back to time_struct using the string? I tested as follows: `f = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)`, `t = time.strftime(f)`. However, `time.strptime(t, f)` produces `'r' is a bad directive in format` for `en_US` locale and `'T' is a bad directive in format` for `fr_FR` locale. What do you suggest?

Comment: This keeps getting weirder: using `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)` returns `'%r'` on `en_US` locale, and it returns `'%T'` on `fr_FR` locale. But I can not find any documentation on the `'%r'` or `'%T'` directives!

Comment: I should have mentioned, `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_T_FMT)` produces `'%a %d %b %Y %r %Z'` on my system for US locale. It produces `'%a %d %b %Y %T'` for FR locale. Notice the unusual `%r` and `%T`? I am on Linux, and I don't see why this did not work exactly like your example.

Comment: @PJSingh the locales are simply different and may be incompatible. This is similar to character encoding - there are simply subtle disagreements you cannot resolve. [_refuse the temptation to guess_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) and either force an exact format or require the locale to be provided. I've updated my answer with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using %c, you can specify how you want to format the date using %a, %b and other directives. For example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')

import datetime
fmt = '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt)
print(time_stamp)

import time
print(time.strptime(time_stamp, fmt))
```

This produces an output that you are looking for:

Output:

```
Mon Dec 21 2020 21:27:50
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=21, tm_min=27, tm_sec=50, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=356, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: I preferred %c because I takes care of things like AM,PM,EST, and the ordering of month or day for diffrent locales. Are we stuck with "hard coding" the time format? (In your example, the order is hard coded to day, month, date, year, etc. Also the assumption is 24 hr format. But some locale's display the year first or use AM/PM).